# ROS/Eclipse: Help needed for launching ROS program in Eclipse

Tags: c++, ros

hopefully someone can help with me this:

Im trying to build and launch my ROS package within eclipse.
I have followed the tutorial from the ROS homepage.
So far eclipse has found the package and its dependencies. (Eclipse
doesnt show any errors).
Also it's possible to build the workspace without error, although I am not sure
if it doing it correctly. When I'm trying to launch (I did a configuration file as the tutorial said) it shows following message:

< terminated > (exit value -1) stargazer_stargazer  Configuration [C++ App] /home/.../app/gtest/libgtest.so

followed this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Reusing_your_shell.27s_environment

Comment: which tutorial are you following ? post the complete error ... be more specific ...

Comment: added the complete error and the link to the tutorial

Comment: I think the main problem is that it doesnt use any launch files to start...trying to solve this right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Seemed that the problem wasnt a problem. You have to configure your launch file at first in Eclipse so that Eclipse will be able to find the roslaunch in /bin folder.